# C++: Finding average for each salesperson from a text file

Tags: c++

I need to calculate the average sales for each salesperson from a text file. My code will produce the correct output as the sample, but will not work if I add more information to the file without manually modifying the code.

I'm completely stuck on this, tried many different methods that I know but they doesn't completely satisfy the question. This is what I have so far.

*Edit:*
*Is there a way to read the file, then add together all the amount that have the same name?*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Sales
{
public:
    int id;
    string name;
    int salesCount = 1;
    double salesAmount;
    double avgSalesAmount;
};

void read()
{
    int i = 0;
    Sales sale[4];
    fstream read;
    read.open("Sales.txt");
    while(!read.eof())
    {
        read.ignore();
        getline(read, sale[i].name);
        read >> sale[i].salesAmount;
        if (sale[i].name == sale[i-1].name)
        {
            sale[i-1].salesAmount = sale[i-1].salesAmount + sale[i].salesAmount;
            sale[i-1].salesCount++;
            sale[i].salesCount = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    read.close();

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {

        if (sale[x].salesCount != 0)
        {
            sale[x].avgSalesAmount = sale[x].salesAmount / sale[x].salesCount;
            cout << sale[x].name << endl;
            cout << sale[x].salesCount << endl;
            cout << sale[x].avgSalesAmount << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample file "Sales.txt":

```
Matthew  
123.45  
Matthew  
432.15  
Brown  
89.95  
Cook  
500.00
```

Sample Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS6jE.png
Current Output (No Formatting): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTA7K.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the static person count in your code, please try to replace the `4` with a larger constant.

```cpp
const int PERSON_COUNT = 100;

void read()
{
    int i = 0;
    Sales sale[PERSON_COUNT];
    fstream read, read2;
    read.open("Sales.txt");
    while(!read.eof())
    {
        read.ignore();
        getline(read, sale[i].name);
        read >> sale[i].salesAmount;
        if (sale[i].name == sale[i-1].name)
        {
            sale[i-1].salesAmount = sale[i-1].salesAmount + sale[i].salesAmount;
            sale[i-1].salesCount++;
            sale[i].salesCount = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    read.close();

    for (int x = 0; x < PERSON_COUNT; x++)
    {

        if (sale[x].salesCount != 0)
        {
            sale[x].avgSalesAmount = sale[x].salesAmount / sale[x].salesCount;
            cout << sale[x].name << endl;
            cout << sale[x].salesCount << endl;
            cout << sale[x].avgSalesAmount << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that using the variable-length array (VLA) in your functions is not recommended practice in most cases since it's a non-standard extension that doesn't work in all implementations. Please consider using [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or other dynamic array solutions.

EDIT:

As Ted Lyngmo suggests, the code above is almost never the correct solution if the input amount is unknown during your coding period. But I'd keep that because it will need little effort for you to fix it if your scenario is simple enough.

Below is my humble refactor for you as a clearer solution. Hope this can enlighten you to build a better program on it.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Sales {
  public:
    int id;
    string name;
    int salesCount = 1;
    double salesAmount;
    double avgSalesAmount;
};

void read() {
    vector<Sales> sale;
    ifstream fin("Sales.txt");

    int i = 0;
    string name;
    double salesAmount;

    while (fin >> name) {
        fin >> salesAmount;
        if (sale.empty() || sale.back().name != name) {
            sale.push_back(Sales{i++, name, 1, salesAmount, 0});
        } else {
            sale.back().salesCount++;
            sale.back().salesAmount += salesAmount;
        }
    }

    fin.close();

    for (auto &s : sale) {
        s.avgSalesAmount = s.salesAmount / s.salesCount;
        cout << s.name << endl;
        cout << s.salesCount << endl;
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << s.avgSalesAmount << endl;
        cout << "---" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

test case:

```
A
1.00
A
2.00
A
3.00
B
2.00
B
3.00
C
4.00
```

```
A
3
2.00
---
B
2
2.50
---
C
1
4.00
---
```

EDIT 2:

If your data doesn't guarantee that records of the same person will come up in a row, in the simplest solution, please refer to [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and use `std::map<std::string, Sale> records` to retrieve the person's record.

Comment: _"please try to replace the 4 with a larger constant"_ is almost never the correct solution when the amount is unknown. I'd remove that part